# Converting spoken numbers to Arabic numerals in Java so "one oh six" does not equal 7

Tags: java, android

I am using the following to convert spoken numbers to their Arabic numeral equivalent in Java. It works for numbers spoken in standard grammar school format: "one hundred and fifty-seven", "six hundred and twelve", etc. However, phrasings that omit the hundreds or thousand designators (such as phone numbers, etc) cause problems: "one oh six" produces "7", and "one fifty-six" results in "57".

Any suggestions regarding how to resolve this?

```
public void parseNumbers(){
    if(szInput != null && szInput.length()> 0)
    {
        szInput = szInput.replaceAll("-", " ");
        szInput = szInput.replaceAll("OH", "ZERO");
        szInput = szInput.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" and", " ");
        String[] splittedParts = szInput.trim().split("\\s+");

        for(String str : splittedParts)
        {
            if(!szlAllowedStrings.contains(str))
            {
                bIsValidInput = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid word found:" + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
        if(bIsValidInput)
        {
            for(String str : splittedParts)
            {
                if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("zero")) {
                    lResult += 0;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("one")) {
                    lResult += 1;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("two")) {
                    lResult += 2;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("three")) {
                    lResult += 3;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("four")) {
                    lResult += 4;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("five")) {
                    lResult += 5;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("six")) {
                    lResult += 6;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("seven")) {
                    lResult += 7;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("eight")) {
                    lResult += 8;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("nine")) {
                    lResult += 9;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("ten")) {
                    lResult += 10;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("eleven")) {
                    lResult += 11;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("twelve")) {
                    lResult += 12;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("thirteen")) {
                    lResult += 13;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("fourteen")) {
                    lResult += 14;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("fifteen")) {
                    lResult += 15;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("sixteen")) {
                    lResult += 16;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("seventeen")) {
                    lResult += 17;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("eighteen")) {
                    lResult += 18;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("nineteen")) {
                    lResult += 19;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("twenty")) {
                    lResult += 20;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("thirty")) {
                    lResult += 30;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("forty")) {
                    lResult += 40;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("fifty")) {
                    lResult += 50;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("sixty")) {
                    lResult += 60;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("seventy")) {
                    lResult += 70;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("eighty")) {
                    lResult += 80;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("ninety")) {
                    lResult += 90;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("hundred")) {
                    lResult *= 100;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("thousand")) {
                    lResult *= 1000;
                    lFinalResult += lResult;
                    lResult=0;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("million")) {
                    lResult *= 1000000;
                    lFinalResult += lResult;
                    lResult=0;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("billion")) {
                    lResult *= 1000000000;
                    lFinalResult += lResult;
                    lResult=0;
                }
                else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("trillion")) {
                    lResult *= 1000000000000L;
                    lFinalResult += lResult;
                    lResult=0;
                }
            }

            lFinalResult += lResult;
            lResult=0;
            szFinalResult = Long.toString(lFinalResult);
            lFinalResult=0;
        }else{//not valid
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bottom elseif, not valid.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bIsValidInput = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: Once you see yourself writing that many `else if` clauses in a row, rethink your code. All of that would be much better handled by defining a string-to-integer map, and looking up values in that map rather than testing one string value after another after another.

You'll need to add "oh" to your map as an alternative for zero.

Then you need to multiply what your accumulated result by ten when one more digit comes along.

That's a rough start. Spoken numbers have more quirks to deal with, but hopefully that rough outline will get your further along.